# SQL Server many-to-many query

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables, let's call them `table1` and `table2`. They both have a column called `ID1` and `ID2` which are respective PK for each of two tables.

I have also another table, called `table3` which contains `ID1` and `ID2`, establishing a many to many relation between these two tables.

What I need is to get all the records from `table2` that are not related with records in `table1`.

Ex.

- Table 1 contains a record with ID = 1
- Table 2 contains two records with ID 1, 2
- Table 3 contains one record with values 1 - 1

I need a query that will give me as result 2.

Can anyone suggest me a way to proceed?

Thanks

Comment: There are about 12000 questions on this topic already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT t2.ID2
    FROM table2 t2
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                         FROM table3 t3
                         WHERE t3.ID2 = t2.ID2);
```

You could also use a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT t2.ID2
    FROM table2 t2
        LEFT JOIN table3 t3
            ON t2.ID2 = t3.ID2
    WHERE t3.ID2 IS NULL;
```

Comment: IN SS 2005+ the first query short circuits.

Comment: @MaiOM: In general, the NOT EXISTS version should be better. See [left join vs. NOT EXISTS](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/03/23/left-outer-join-vs-not-exists/) and [NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL: SQL Server](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/).

Comment: I would +1 again if I could for referencing Quassnoi's excellent article.